# First rock song to use the 3/4 time signature?

Tags: rock

The three-four time signature is frequently used in swing music or dance music. But what was the first rock song to use this time signature?

Comment: Time signatures predate rock and I'm not sure most music fans would be able to tell what songs have what time signatures.

Comment: More seriously, we don't know what rock is yet : http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-defines-rock-music-as-a-genre  :)

Comment: @Dom Um... yes, I am aware that time signatures predate rock. I'm simply asking what was the first song in a particular genre to use it.

Comment: If I had more rep I would vote to close. The question depends on the definition of "rock", a concept so vague and contentious that you will have severe difficulty finding two people who agree on which songs do and do not qualify.

Comment: What I'm saying it's kind of odd to ask to ask a question about when the first time a concept was used in a specific genre when the concept exists independent of any genre. I'm sure the first rock and roll album has a song that is at least partially in 3/4

Comment: …but Rock & Roll is not Rock. There was a break between the two. I like the question, actually - made me think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might depend on what you consider 'rock' & whether 6/8 would sneak in as 3/4- but how about The Animals, House of the Rising Sun. 1964.

Or Moody Blues - Go Now.

Beatles - You've Got to Hide Your Love Away. 1964.

The trouble with the 60's is rock hadn't quite been invented yet, so the answer might turn out to be Hendrix.

Comment: [6/8 _is not_ 3/4](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25035/does-3-4-time-signature-differ-from-6-8)

Comment: Accepting this on You've Got To Hide Your Love Away - Beatles.

Comment: @DJAftershock every google image of the score I can find has that one as 6/8... just sayin'!

Comment: You've Got To Hide Your Love Away does have a strong 'One-and-a-three, Two-and-a' feel, more typical of 6/8 than 3/4

Answer (score 3):

Three I can think of, in ascending order of both rockiness and release date

Bob Dylan - *The times they are a changin'* (1964)
The Beatles - *Norwegian Wood* (1965)
Jimi Hendrix - *Manic Depression* (1967)

I'm not sure if the first two are really 'rock', and the I can't remember if the last one sticks to its 3/4 guns all the way through.

Screamin Jay Hawkins *I put a spell on you* (1956) also has a triple-time feel, though online sources disagree on the actual time signature. Again, maybe not really 'rock', though the vocal delivery is rockier than most...

Comment: Watch out for the 6/8 police ;) … only the Hendrix is really 3/4 to my mind. Hawkins too, but I'm not sure it's rock, probably still 'blues' for want of a better word. Interestingly, all the [better-known] covers go for 6/8 or 12/8 rather than the straight 3/4

Comment: @Tetsujin ...ready to beat me with their batons, no doubt :)  And yes, you can't necessarily say that something is *definitively* in a particular time signature unless the original composer scored it that way, though at least some online sources give 3/4 for the three I listed.

Comment: I can transcribe a song in 4/4 into 3/4. There are aspects that make a song 3/4 vs. 6/8. I really don't think that the OP is after a specific time signature, but a certain feel that is associated with that time signature.

Answer (score 2):

Leonard Cohen's 'One of Us Cannot Be Wrong' is a song with a strong waltz-time feel. It was recorded a few months after 'Manic Depression', so maybe it was pipped at the post, though.